# Translate div on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I have a div in a div.
The first div has a unknown height. The second one has the height of 125px.

I want to make the second one a sticky div which is only sticky in this div.

The grey box is the container and the social media div next to it should be sticky.

[image: Picture to show you what it currently looks like]

After the container more content will come, so I cant use `position: fixed`. I tried to use `position: absolute` and change the `top` value or the `transform: translate`, but when I Do that Chrome is jittering around.

Code that I tried to use:

```
$offset = $(".social-media").offset().top;
$containerHeight = $(".sticky-container").height();
$bottom = $containerHeight + $(".sticky-container").offset().top;
$maxPoint = $containerHeight - $(".social-media").height();
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $offset){
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $bottom){
            $(".social-media").css({transform: "translate(0px,"+$maxPoint+"px)"});
        }else{
            $scroll = $(window).scrollTop() - $offset;
            $(".social-media").css({transform: "translate(0px,"+$scroll+"px)"});
        }
    }else{
        $(".social-media").css({transform: "translate(0px,0px)"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML or a JSFiddle/Codepen example of what you currently have?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d0fx8jcL/ Here is your fiddle... Chrome dosen't jitter here... idk why it does on my site :(

Answer (score 0):

Since the jsbin you provided shows the solution works without jittering, the problem might lie in the repaints triggered by other elements of your site, not the code you pasted. Have a look at the [Google's repaint optimization guidelines](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/simplify-paint-complexity-and-reduce-paint-areas), it might help you identify the issues that cause the jittering.

Comment: There is no other thing moving or transforming on this site... only the stickybox